# Newrelic override application name on the fly

Tags: node.js, logging, newrelic

According to the doc there has to be a `newrelic.js` in the root of the Node app where the config sits, including the name of the application where we want to log to.

Is it possible to override the application name on the fly for some exceptional cases? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can send [NewRelic Insights API](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/insights-data-sources/custom-data/insert-custom-events-insights-api) and gives a different/dynamic application name in parameters

> The New Relic Insights API lets you store custom events in Insights; these events appear in Insights as a new event type. Then, you can use NRQL or the Insights event explorer to sample, query, and chart this new data.

Comment: Can you show an example how to do it? I wasn't able to override the application name.